# How can I redirect several different files to an url using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to edit .htaccess placing the lines below into a single line:

```
Redirect 301 "/smartphone" "/roster.php"
Redirect 301 "/mobile" "/roster.php"
```

**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding `RedirectMatch` directive allows you to use a regex. For example:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(smartphone|mobile) /roster.php
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch